# Angular 2: Receiving error due to slowness in receiving server data

Tags: angular, typescript

In the constructor of my service class, I place a http call to the the server to retrieve product category data which is stored in the productCategories array. Then in the ngInit() function of my component, I place a call to the service to retrieve the productCategories array but I get an error that the productCategories is undefined.

What appears to be happening is the constructor of the service places the call to the server then returns before the product category data is retrieved. When the component calls the getCategory(x, y) method of the service for this data, the previous call to the server from the service's constructor is still not complete hence it declares the productCategories array undefined. Then the call completes and the productCategories array is logged to the console.

How do I fix this?

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductCategoryService {
  private productCategories: ProductCategory[];
  private categoriesUrl = "/api/product/categories";

  constructor(private http: Http) { 
    console.log('ProductCategory.constructor() called');
    this.getProductCategoriesDb();
  }

  private getProductCategoriesDb() {
    console.log('ProductCategory.getCategories() called');

    this.http.get(this.categoriesUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then((response: Response) => {
        this.productCategories = response.json();
        console.log('this.productCategories = ' + 
JSON.stringify(this.productCategories));
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  public getProductCategory(name, type) {
    return this.productCategories
      .filter(category => (category.name == name && category.type == type))[0];
  }
}
```

Component:

```
export class ProductCategoryComponent implements OnInit {
  category: string;
  type: string;
  productCategory: ProductCategory = new ProductCategory();

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private productCategoryService: 
ProductCategoryService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.category = params["category"];
      this.type = params["type"];

      console.log("category = " + this.category)
      console.log("type = " + this.type)


      this.productCategory = 
this.productCategoryService.getProductCategory(this.category, this.type);
      console.log("productCategory = " + this.productCategory);

    })  
  }

}
```

Sequence of logged statements:

ProductCategory.constructor() called ---- product-category.service.ts:27

ProductCategory.getCategories() called ---- product-category.component.ts:23

Error: productCategories array undefined:

ProductCategoryComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at ProductCategoryService.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/product-category/product-category.service.ts.ProductCategoryService.getProductCategory (product-category.service.ts:39)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (product-category.component.ts:27)
    at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError (

Finally productCategories array printed --- product-category.service.ts:33

this.productCategories = [{"_id":"599c5d93f36d286317108ffd","name":"Furniture","type":"Living Room","image":[{"label":"Living Room","name":"LivingRoom1.jpg"},{"label":"Sofas","name":"LivingRoom2.jpg"},{"label":"Sleeper","name":"LivingRoom3.jpg"},{"label":"Loveseats","name":"LivingRoom4.jpg"},{"label":"Chairs","name":"LivingRoom5.jpg"},{"label":"Ottomans","name":"LivingRoom6.jpg"},{"label":"Chaisers","name":"LivingRoom7.jpg"},{"label":"Recliners","name":"LivingRoom8.jpg"},{"label":"Sectionals","name":"LivingRoom9.jpg"},{"label":"Occasional Tables","name":"LivingRoom10.jpg"}],"items":["Sofas","Sleepers","Loveseats","Chairs","Ottomans","Chaises","Recliners","Sectionals","Occasional Tables"]}]

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is don't fix it, rewrite it.
Your reasoning behind the error being thrown is correct, but maybe you should consider a different approach when handling the data from server.

This is a first step, which can be improved on iteratively further.

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductCategoryService {
  productCategoriesSbj: ReplaySubject<ProductCategory[]> = new ReplaySubject();
  private categoriesUrl = "/api/product/categories";

  constructor(private http: Http) { 
  }

  getProductCategoriesDb(): Observable<ProductCategory[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.categoriesUrl)
      .subscribe(response => this.productCategoriesSbj.next(response.json()))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getProductCategory(categories: ProductCategory[], name: string, type: string) {
    return categories.filter(category =>
        (category.name == name && category.type == type)
    )[0];
  }
}
```

and then in your component:

```
export class ProductCategoryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  category: string;

  type: string;

  productCategory: ProductCategory = new ProductCategory();

  productCategorySub: Subscription = new Subscription();

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private productCategoryService: ProductCategoryService){
  }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.category = params["category"] || '';
      this.type = params["type"] || '';

      this.productCategoryService.getProductCategoriesDb();
      productCategorySub = this.productCategoryService
          .productCategoriesSbj
          .subscribe(categories => {
              // now categories contain parsed response from the server
              this.productCategory = this.productCategoryService
                  .getProductCategory(categories, this.category, this.type);
          });
    })  
  }
}

 ngOnDestroy() {
     // unsubscribe from observable to avoid memory leaks
     this.productCategorySub.unsubscribe();
 }
```

Not many explanations, but I hope it helps.

Comment: This is definitely an improvement. But the only problem with this is I have to make a call to the server on each call to getProductProductDb(). I used the constructor because I was hoping I could retrieve the category data in one call and store it in an array. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Still calling method from constructor doesn't seem right. Maybe a call should be made from feature module main component in this case or the `AppComponent` if it is the only module. Reagring, storing the state in service it is posible and `BehaviorSubject` is good option for doing that. I will update the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write `ReplaySubject`.